# PHP xml configuration package or framework?

Tags: php, package, config

I am looking for some type of framework or package or library for PHP that would manage my PHP web apps configuration parameters.  Is there such a thing?  Rather than repeatedly opening a file and reading and parsing the contents, is there something already existing I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have liked to have used Zend_Config but just couldn't get it to work.  I settled for the less programatically sexy alternative : SimpleXMLElement.  Sometimes, in programming as in life, we choose to settle for the practical rather than the sexy.  A Volkswagen instead of a Ferrari.  Sarah Rodriguez instead of Pamela Anderson.  Now I need to find something for Javascript.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html), you have there an xml version, but also ini, json or yaml.

## update

I don't understand exactly your usage scenario and the main idea of Zend_Config is to remove the configuration data from various parts of the application and to put it in only one place. But you can adapt it to your use. If you  have a config file with your users to be parsed, you can update that config independently and you application does not have to know how many users are in the file.

Comment: I have a requirement where I need to load collections of configuration information into an array and this collection can vary.  For example, I have a collection of different users that I will need to parse but I won't know in advance how many users I will have.  Can I do this with Zend Config?

Comment: can you possibly provide an example of it's usage? I've tried to use some of the examples on the website but get the error message:Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Config_Xml' not found  I downloaded the framework and included it on the php include path.  I am then calling it like so: $config = new Zend_Config_Xml('config/config.xml', 'eventinfo'); but get the above error message.

Comment: After spending a day fooling with Zend_Config, perhaps it is better just to read from a file in PHP